# How to handle text selection from div in i-Pad using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Currently I am using "text-highlighter.js" for highlight text and change the colour of text. It works fine in desktop but , It **dint work in the i-Pad.**

Can anyone suggest **which javascript event should be fire to select text in i-pad chrome browser.**

/**
 * @license jQuery Text Highlighter
 * Copyright (C) 2011 - 2013 by mirz
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */

(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var nodeTypes = {
        ELEMENT_NODE: 1,
        TEXT_NODE: 3
    };

```
var plugin = {
    name: 'textHighlighter'
};

function TextHighlighter(element, options) {
    this.context = element;
    this.$context = $(element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, $[plugin.name].defaults, options);

    this.init();
}

TextHighlighter.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.$context.addClass(this.options.contextClass);
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.unbindEvents();
        this.$context.removeClass(this.options.contextClass);
        this.$context.removeData(plugin.name);
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        this.$context.bind('mouseup', {self: this}, this.highlightHandler);
    },

    unbindEvents: function() {
        this.$context.unbind('mouseup', this.highlightHandler);
        //
    },

    highlightHandler: function(event) {
        var self = event.data.self;
        self.doHighlight();
    },

    /**
     * Highlights currently selected text.
     */
    doHighlight: function() {
        var range = this.getCurrentRange();
        if (!range || range.collapsed) return;
        var rangeText = range.toString();

        if (this.options.onBeforeHighlight(range) == true) {
            var $wrapper = $.textHighlighter.createWrapper(this.options);

            var createdHighlights = this.highlightRange(range, $wrapper);
            var normalizedHighlights = this.normalizeHighlights(createdHighlights);

            this.options.onAfterHighlight(normalizedHighlights, rangeText);
        }

        this.removeAllRanges();
    },

    /**
     * Returns first range of current selection object.
     */
    getCurrentRange: function() {
        var selection = this.getCurrentSelection();

        var range;
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        return range;
    },

    removeAllRanges: function() {
        var selection = this.getCurrentSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
    },

    /**
     * Returns current selection object.
     */
    getCurrentSelection: function() {
        var currentWindow = this.getCurrentWindow();
        var selection;

        if (currentWindow.getSelection) {
            selection = currentWindow.getSelection();
        } else if ($('iframe').length) {
            $('iframe', top.document).each(function() {
                if (this.contentWindow === currentWindow) {
                    selection = rangy.getIframeSelection(this);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            selection = rangy.getSelection();
        }

        return selection;
    },

    /**
     * Returns owner window of this.context.
     */
    getCurrentWindow: function() {
        var currentDoc = this.getCurrentDocument();
        if (currentDoc.defaultView) {
            return currentDoc.defaultView; // Non-IE
        } else {
            return currentDoc.parentWindow; // IE
        }
    },

    /**
     * Returns owner document of this.context.
     */
    getCurrentDocument: function() {
        // if ownerDocument is null then context is document
        return this.context.ownerDocument ? this.context.ownerDocument : this.context;
    },

    /**
     * Wraps given range (highlights it) object in the given wrapper.
     */
    highlightRange: function(range, $wrapper) {
        if (range.collapsed) return;

        // Don't highlight content of these tags
        var ignoreTags = ['SCRIPT', 'STYLE', 'SELECT', 'BUTTON', 'OBJECT', 'APPLET'];
        var startContainer = range.startContainer;
        var endContainer = range.endContainer;
        var ancestor = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        var goDeeper = true;

        if (range.endOffset == 0) {
            while (!endContainer.previousSibling && endContainer.parentNode != ancestor) {
                endContainer = endContainer.parentNode;
            }
            endContainer = endContainer.previousSibling;
        } else if (endContainer.nodeType == nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
            if (range.endOffset < endContainer.nodeValue.length) {
                endContainer.splitText(range.endOffset);
            }
        } else if (range.endOffset > 0) {
            endContainer = endContainer.childNodes.item(range.endOffset - 1);
        }

        if (startContainer.nodeType == nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
            if (range.startOffset == startContainer.nodeValue.length) {
                goDeeper = false;
            } else if (range.startOffset > 0) {
                startContainer = startContainer.splitText(range.startOffset);
                if (endContainer == startContainer.previousSibling) endContainer = startContainer;
            }
        } else if (range.startOffset < startContainer.childNodes.length) {
            startContainer = startContainer.childNodes.item(range.startOffset);
        } else {
            startContainer = startContainer.nextSibling;
        }

        var done = false;
        var node = startContainer;
        var highlights = [];

        do {
            if (goDeeper && node.nodeType == nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
                if (/\S/.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                    var wrapper = $wrapper.clone(true).get(0);
                    var nodeParent = node.parentNode;

                    // highlight if node is inside the context
                    if ($.contains(this.context, nodeParent) || nodeParent === this.context) {
                        var highlight = $(node).wrap(wrapper).parent().get(0);
                        highlights.push(highlight);
                    }
                }

                goDeeper = false;
            }
            if (node == endContainer && (!endContainer.hasChildNodes() || !goDeeper)) {
                done = true;
            }

            if ($.inArray(node.tagName, ignoreTags) != -1) {
                goDeeper = false;
            }
            if (goDeeper && node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            } else if (node.nextSibling != null) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
                goDeeper = true;
            } else {
                node = node.parentNode;
                goDeeper = false;
            }
        } while (!done);

        return highlights;
    },

    /**
     * Normalizes highlights - nested highlights are flattened and sibling higlights are merged.
     */
    normalizeHighlights: function(highlights) {
        this.flattenNestedHighlights(highlights);
        this.mergeSiblingHighlights(highlights);

        // omit removed nodes
        var normalizedHighlights = $.map(highlights, function(hl) {
            if (typeof hl.parentElement != 'undefined') { // IE
                return hl.parentElement != null ? hl : null;
            } else {
                return hl.parentNode != null ? hl : null;
            }
        });

        return normalizedHighlights;
    },

    flattenNestedHighlights: function(highlights) {
        var self = this;

        $.each(highlights, function(i) {
            var $highlight = $(this);
            var $parent = $highlight.parent();
            var $parentPrev = $parent.prev();
            var $parentNext = $parent.next();

            if (self.isHighlight($parent)) {
                if ($parent.css('background-color') != $highlight.css('background-color')) {
                    if (self.isHighlight($parentPrev) && !$highlight.get(0).previousSibling
                        && $parentPrev.css('background-color') != $parent.css('background-color')
                        && $parentPrev.css('background-color') == $highlight.css('background-color')) {

                        $highlight.insertAfter($parentPrev);
                    }

                    if (self.isHighlight($parentNext) && !$highlight.get(0).nextSibling
                        && $parentNext.css('background-color') != $parent.css('background-color')
                        && $parentNext.css('background-color') == $highlight.css('background-color')) {

                        $highlight.insertBefore($parentNext);
                    }

                    if ($parent.is(':empty')) {
                        $parent.remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    var newNode = document.createTextNode($parent.text());

                    $parent.empty();
                    $parent.append(newNode);
                    $(highlights[i]).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    },

    mergeSiblingHighlights: function(highlights) {
        var self = this;

        function shouldMerge(current, node) {
            return node && node.nodeType == nodeTypes.ELEMENT_NODE
                && $(current).css('background-color') == $(node).css('background-color')
                && $(node).hasClass(self.options.highlightedClass)
                ? true : false;
        }

        $.each(highlights, function() {
            var highlight = this;

            var prev = highlight.previousSibling;
            var next = highlight.nextSibling;

            if (shouldMerge(highlight, prev)) {
                var mergedTxt = $(prev).text() + $(highlight).text();
                $(highlight).text(mergedTxt);
                $(prev).remove();
            }
            if (shouldMerge(highlight, next)) {
                var mergedTxt = $(highlight).text() + $(next).text();
                $(highlight).text(mergedTxt);
                $(next).remove();
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Sets color of future highlights.
     */
    setColor: function(color) {
        this.options.color = color;
    },

    /**
     * Returns current highlights color.
     */
    getColor: function() {
        return this.options.color;
    },

    /**
     * Removes all highlights in given element or in context if no element given.
     */
    removeHighlights: function(element) {
        var container = (element !== undefined ? element : this.context);

        var unwrapHighlight = function(highlight) {
            return $(highlight).contents().unwrap().get(0);
        };

        var mergeSiblingTextNodes = function(textNode) {
            var prev = textNode.previousSibling;
            var next = textNode.nextSibling;

            if (prev && prev.nodeType == nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
                textNode.nodeValue = prev.nodeValue + textNode.nodeValue;
                prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
            }
            if (next && next.nodeType == nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
                textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
                next.parentNode.removeChild(next);
            }
        };

        var self = this;
        var $highlights = this.getAllHighlights(container, true);
        $highlights.each(function() {
            if (self.options.onRemoveHighlight(this) == true) {
                var textNode = unwrapHighlight(this);
                mergeSiblingTextNodes(textNode);
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Returns all highlights in given container. If container is a highlight itself and
     * andSelf is true, container will be also returned
     */
    getAllHighlights: function(container, andSelf) {
        var classSelectorStr = '.' + this.options.highlightedClass;
        var $highlights = $(container).find(classSelectorStr);
        if (andSelf == true && $(container).hasClass(this.options.highlightedClass)) {
            $highlights = $highlights.add(container);
        }
        return $highlights;
    },

    /**
     * Returns true if element is highlight, ie. has proper class.
     */
    isHighlight: function($el) {
        return $el.hasClass(this.options.highlightedClass);
    },

    /**
     * Serializes all highlights to stringified JSON object.
     */
    serializeHighlights: function() {
        var $highlights = this.getAllHighlights(this.context);
        var refEl = this.context;
        var hlDescriptors = [];
        var self = this;

        var getElementPath = function (el, refElement) {
            var path = [];

            do {
                var elIndex = $.inArray(el, el.parentNode.childNodes);
                path.unshift(elIndex);
                el = el.parentNode;
            } while (el !== refElement);

            return path;
        };

        $highlights.each(function(i, highlight) {
            var offset = 0; // Hl offset from previous sibling within parent node.
            var length = highlight.firstChild.length;
            var hlPath = getElementPath(highlight, refEl);
            var wrapper = $(highlight).clone().empty().get(0).outerHTML;

            if (highlight.previousSibling && highlight.previousSibling.nodeType === nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
                offset = highlight.previousSibling.length;
            }

            hlDescriptors.push([
                wrapper,
                $(highlight).text(),
                hlPath.join(':'),
                offset,
                length
            ]);
        });

        return JSON.stringify(hlDescriptors);
    },

    /**
     * Deserializes highlights from stringified JSON given as parameter.
     */
    deserializeHighlights: function(json) {
        try {
            var hlDescriptors = JSON.parse(json);
        } catch (e) {
            throw "Can't parse serialized highlights: " + e;
        }
        var highlights = [];
        var self = this;

        var deserializationFn = function (hlDescriptor) {
            var wrapper = hlDescriptor[0];
            var hlText = hlDescriptor[1];
            var hlPath = hlDescriptor[2].split(':');
            var elOffset = hlDescriptor[3];
            var hlLength = hlDescriptor[4];
            var elIndex = hlPath.pop();
            var idx = null;
            var node = self.context;

            while ((idx = hlPath.shift()) !== undefined) {
                node = node.childNodes[idx];
            }

            if (node.childNodes[elIndex-1] && node.childNodes[elIndex-1].nodeType === nodeTypes.TEXT_NODE) {
                elIndex -= 1;
            }

            var textNode = node.childNodes[elIndex];
            var hlNode = textNode.splitText(elOffset);
            hlNode.splitText(hlLength);

            if (hlNode.nextSibling && hlNode.nextSibling.nodeValue == '') {
                hlNode.parentNode.removeChild(hlNode.nextSibling);
            }

            if (hlNode.previousSibling && hlNode.previousSibling.nodeValue == '') {
                hlNode.parentNode.removeChild(hlNode.previousSibling);
            }

            var highlight = $(hlNode).wrap(wrapper).parent().get(0);
            highlights.push(highlight);
        };

        $.each(hlDescriptors, function(i, hlDescriptor) {
            try {
                deserializationFn(hlDescriptor);
            } catch (e) {
                console && console.warn
                    && console.warn("Can't deserialize " + i + "-th descriptor. Cause: " + e);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return highlights;
    }

};

/**
 * Returns TextHighlighter instance.
 */
$.fn.getHighlighter = function() {
    return this.data(plugin.name);
};

$.fn[plugin.name] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, plugin.name)) {
            $.data(this, plugin.name, new TextHighlighter(this, options));
        }
    });
};

$.textHighlighter = {
    /**
     * Returns HTML element to wrap selected text in.
     */
    createWrapper: function(options) {
        return $('<span></span>')
            .css('backgroundColor', options.color)
            .addClass(options.highlightedClass);
    },
    defaults: {
        color: '#ffff7b',
        highlightedClass: 'highlighted',
        contextClass: 'highlighter-context',
        onRemoveHighlight: function() { return true; },
        onBeforeHighlight: function() { return true; },
        onAfterHighlight: function() { }
    }
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: I didn't found any solution yet.